# Table border-radius

Tags: html, html-table, css

How to set a border-radius for a table. Read a lot of information about this, but nothing concrete.

```
<table id="table-prices"> 
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="table-main">Длина</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ширина</td>
      <td>190 см</td>
      <td>200 см</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>80 см</td>
      <td>5496</td>
      <td>5496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>140 см</td>
      <td>5496</td>
      <td>5496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Цены указаны в грн.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

table {
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border-collapse: separate; 
 border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
 border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Almost done. But after border of table the angles are displaying. When I seting the owerflow-hiding - the grid inside table is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `border-collapse: collapse;` than `border-radius` won't work, for example

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju7gQ/)</kbd>
 *(The other `table` is using `border-collapse: collapse;` and hence `border-radius` fails)*

---

It may happen that most of the users use CSS Reset Stylesheet, and it uses the snippet below..

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

So it fails, inorder to override that for a particular `table` you need to use

```
table.class_name {
    border-collapse: separate; /* Overriding collapsed border */
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Where GCyrillus already pointed you about the spacing, but he missed out the `separate` value for the `border-collapse` property.

Comment: Great note about border collapse, never knew that.

Comment: It works, but in example the table is whith out grid, when i set to td a border - the table looks terribly(becouse it haven't a border-collapse)

Comment: @Barns I already gave you the solution for that as well

Comment: @Mr. Alien thx, perhaps I dont understand something

Answer (score 0):

to collapse `table` borders and still have access to `border-radius`, you should set `border-spacing:0;` instead of `border-collapse:collapse;`